# How to define array of bigint array in gorm model

Tags: go-gorm

If I have a table and it has a column can return data like
`{{1,2},{2,3}}`
How can I define this in model

Tried pq.Array(pq.Int64Array)

Comment: Can you give details about the column type in the database?

Comment: I used postgresql, the column type is bigInt[][2]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`NumericArray`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgtype?utm_source=godoc#NumericArray)

Definition for [`NumericArray`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgtype?utm_source=godoc#NumericArray)

```
type NumericArray struct {
    Elements   []Numeric
    Dimensions []ArrayDimension
    Status     Status
}
```

Definition for [`Numeric`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgtype#Numeric)

```
type Numeric struct {
    Int              *big.Int
    Exp              int32
    Status           Status
    NaN              bool
    InfinityModifier InfinityModifier
}
```

Definition for [`ArrayDimension`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgtype#ArrayDimension)

```
type ArrayDimension struct {
    Length     int32
    LowerBound int32
}
```